# Error: cannot find symbol ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to create some kind of list to store values from the array 'table'. (I'm using a arraylist here, but should I be using a list instead?) However, every time I try to compile, it throws the following error:

cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ArrayList
location: class players.TablePlayer

The code is below.

```
public class TablePlayer extends Player {

    int[][] table;
    ArrayList goodMoves;


    public TablePlayer(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    public int move() {
        int oppLast = opponentLastMove();
        int myLast = myLastMove();
        if (!isLegalMove(oppLast)) {
            return 0; // temporary
        }
        if (wonLast()) {
            table[oppLast][myLast] = 1;
            table[myLast][oppLast] = -1;
        }
        if ((wonLast() == false) && (oppLast != myLast)) {
            table[oppLast][myLast] = -1;
            table[myLast][oppLast] = 1;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < table.length; j++) {
                if (table[i][j] == 1) {
                    goodMoves.add(table[i][j]);
                }
            }
        }

        return oppLast; // temporary
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        int[][] table = new int[7][7];
        ArrayList<int> goodMoves = new ArrayList<int>();
    }
}
```

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you're just missing the import.

Comment: A decent Java IDE would help you with that.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Do you have an import statement in the top of the file?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved the errors, but it's thrown a new error. warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to add(E) as a member of the raw type java.util.ArrayList

Comment: Using an `ArrayList<Integer>` instead of an `ArrayList` should remove that warning.

Comment: I added in the 'Integer' generic, but still throwing the same error.

Answer (score 2):

While doing any java program just

`import java.util.*;`

Because * will import all the packages from util.

And all the basic package are present in that java.util like Scanner, ArrayList, etc...

So to avoid errors first check you have imported that.

Answer (score 0):

Before use a class, you need to import it into you class file definition.

Add it on top of your file:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
```

For more info about imports, look it up [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html)

It is recommended to learn how to use a IDE, like [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org), Netbeans. It will help you with these common mistakes when we are programming in Java (in this case) outside a integrated environment.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying using Dr. Java right now, but having some trouble with it.

Comment: I recommend Eclipse IDE. Try some tutorial to start things up.

Answer (score -4):

I am new to the community and on a path of learning now.
But I think the main problem is of int

Wrong

```
ArrayList <int> goodMoves = new ArrayList <int>();
```

Right

```
ArrayList <Integer> goodMoves = new ArrayList <Integer>();
```

Comment: This is an error ("unexpected type"), but it is not the reason for the error "cannot find symbol".